# Conditional Formatting not enough

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set conditional formatting in a specific group of cells J9:N12 with a locked cell I9 (110). In Cells J9:N12 I need the conditional formatting to set 1,2,7,8,13,14 as Black Fill w/ White Text, 3,4,9,10,15,16 as Red Fill w/ Black Text, 5,6,11,12,17,18 as Blue Fill w/ White Text. Then if I Change (I9) to 277 the Fills would change to reflect Brown/Orange/Yellow in place of the Black/Red/Blue.

Yes, I can Conditional Format the cells I need based on the information set in cell (I9) 110 or 277.

The series of numbers I need to format is greater than 120. I cannot set Conditional Formatting for each specific number needed. Minimallistically I need to be able to set Conditional Formatting to around 150-160 numbers.

I don't know if I need to utilize VBA or if Conditional Formatting is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional formatting for this. I'd be tempted to put the number series in an array and test for a find in the array using `MATCH`. This way, you'd only need as many conditional formatting rules as there are number series.

I'm not certain, but I believe you can't write an array directly into a conditional format rule, but you could refer to it from something like a range name. In any event, a range name would be easier to manage if you needed to change any of the number series.

For example, in the black/brown case, you could create a range name (Formulas->Define Name), called black-brown, and in the Refers To window, have the formula:

```
={1,2,7,8,13,14}
```

Then your conditional formatting rule would be something like:

```
=AND($I$9=110,NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B2,black_brown,0))))
```

Note my cell to be tested is in B2 - change that to whatever you need.

You'd just add rules for each of your number series cases, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I tried your idea and it won't work the way I need it to. I came up with another idea. I created a separate column and inputted this formula (I'm only focusing on Black/Brown at the moment) =IFS(F5=1,"BLK",F5=2,"BLK") and so on. Then set Conditional Formatting to the cell I need formatting and boom it works. Now my issue is to get the formatting for Brown to work. I've tried implementing this way =IF(D5<220,True,False)&IFS(F5=1,"BLK",F5=2,"BLK") which come back as TRUEBLK. Since Black and Brown are interchangeable this should of been a no brainer.

Comment: But unfortunately, I can get the Conditional Formatting to go for the Black but not the Brown. Is there a way to set conditional formatting off two conditions with formulas? I've tried several different variations of IF/IFS/AND/ISFORMULA but the Condition for the Black seems to overpower any Condition I create for the Brown

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing all the formulas and conditional formatting rules. I'd suggest you pose a second question - and try to include as much information as possible.

Comment: Thanks, Ambie. For all your help. I was able to finally get the conditional formatting to go through. I had to take my eyes off of it for a day. When I was writing the formula I forgot the parenthesis in both the formula and the Conditional formating. I was going over too much information across multiple resources. Sometimes its the simplest answer.